# How to run an API every x minutes in IOS background even app is closed

Tags: ios, swift, service, background, task

I have to run an api in background mode and my application is not a navigation or music app.I have to run a service every 10 minutes in IOS background mode is this possible and valid for app store thank you.
Note = (Swift3,4)

Comment: Read this [Background Execution](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW8).  You should update your question to reflect why you are need your app to run in this mode.

Comment: Have you found any solution?